# Temporarily Disallow JQuery Toggle

Tags: jquery

I have a menu that is **toggled** when a user selects a link. The menu had **different** show and hide **animations** attached, and I want to **prevent** toggling while the animation is running. The following snippet works, but flips the state of **toggle** if the link is clicked quickly twice (i.e. if the user clicks the link quickly twice, the next click will trigger the same action):

```
<a href="" id="button">Menu</a>
<div id="menu">...</a>

<script>
$("#button").toggle(
    function (e) { 
      if $("#menu").is(":animated")) return false;
      $("#menu").show("drop", {}, "slow"); 
    }, 
    function (e) { 
      if ("#menu").is(":animated")) return false;
      $("#menu").hide("bounce", {}, "slow"); 
    }
);
</script>
```

How can I prevent switching states within toggle?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't keep editing the question, make an applicable example when first posting :)

Comment: Sorry! The actual script is very large and I wanted to increase the readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), and check the state of the element *inside* the `click` handler, using the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/), and [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selectors, like this:

```
$("#button").click(function () { 
  var menu = $("#menu:not(:animated)");
  if(menu.is(":visible")) menu.hide("bounce", {}, "slow");
  else menu.show("drop", {}, "slow"); 
});
```

This doesn't rely on the state, which is a bit simpler :)

Comment: Hi Nick. Sorry I forgot to mention that I am running different show and hide animations. Any ways to add support for this?

Comment: @Kevin: Updated, check it out, this checks for the state inside the click, rather than the state of the functions themselves.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry again for the confusion.